# Create char from char* that includes escape character

Tags: c, pointers, char

Consider the following char* example:

```
char* s = "\n";
```

How can this be converted into a single char that represents the new line character like so:

```
char c = '\n';
```

In addition to processing newlines I also need to be able to convert any character with an escape character preceeding it into a char. How is this possible?

Comment: `char c = *s;` works. The `'\n'` inside the string is only two characters in source form: after compiling it is a single character; the same for all other escape character. The string `"fo\111\tar"`, after compiling, has 7 characters (the 6 visible in the source code and a null terminator).

Comment: @pmg - That's an answer not a comment post it!

Comment: @pmg : JonH is right. post it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`char c = *s;` works.

The `'\n'` inside the string is only two characters in source form: after compiling it is a single character; the same for all other escape character.

The string `"fo\111\tar"`, after compiling, has 7 characters (the 6 visible in the source code (`'f'`, `'o'`, `'\111'`, `'\t'`, `'a'`, and `'r'`) and a null terminator).

Answer (score 3):

Dereference it:

```
char* s = "\n";
char c = *s;
```

Answer (score 2):

As others said, the newline is actually only one character in memory.  To get a single character from a string pointer, you can access your pointer as if it is an array (assuming, of course, that there is memory allocated for the string pointed to):

```
char* s = "\n";
char  c = s[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like that?

```
char * s = "\n";
char c = *s;
```